Deleted Comments
As far as I can tell, a number of my comments have been deleted in recent days. There does not appear to me to be any notification to me of the fact that this has happened nor any explanation of why it has been done or by whom.
Edit: Am I correct in thinking that there is no notification that a comment has been deleted or any explanation if why.
There appears to be no consistency in relation to deletion of comments.

You are correct that there is no notification when a comment is deleted. This is because comments are meant to be temporary.
If you see comments that you believe don't need to be around any more per the policy linked above, please flag them. Sooner or later, the moderators will review and either act or or decline your flag. There could be many explanations for any inconsistency of outcome that you perceive, but the first hypothesis I would recommend is that we simply haven't gotten around to the ones that you're surprised are still around.
